# Connection via Ethernet cable working, connected via wireless router but not working

Tags: mac, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, internet-connection

I have internet connection at work via the connection in the wall and a ethernet cable to my mac.

Today I brought my wireless N-router from home and plugged the ethernet cable to it and then tried to connect my mac wirelessly via the router. The computer connected directly after choosing the router, had the same name and password as when I use it at home. The computer says connected and it gets the same IP address as when Im connected (system prefs. > network) but I cannot go online. In system prefs. > network everything is greenlit and OK.

Do I need to reset, change anything else? What have I missed? Or is there any external reason why I cannot connect via the router wirelessly but directly to the computer with the sam cable?

Comment: Connection with ethernet cable and router works too

Comment: Anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

at your job you get an IP address by DHCP let say 192.168.1.150
then you connect that cable to your wireless router ...
but your wireless router also probably has NAT and DHCP serving its own downstream ports...
if your router's DHCP also assigns IPs on the same net  192.168.1.0 then you will never reach your work net nor Internet either...
BTW you know companies usually hate employes doing what you are doing right? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the info, how can I solve it? Btw, it is allowed here :)

Comment: and would that explain how I can connect via the router with cable?

Comment: you have to see your router DHCP and check the IPs it's providing to downstream clients. You have to be shure your router assings IPs that do not conflict with the IP your router gets from your company.
That means they have to belong to different subnetworks